# Как добавить еще одну полосу градиента,

Tags: android

Я добавил как `background` такой градиент на экран

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#0019A8"
        android:centerColor="#4C5CB1"
        android:endColor="#0019A8"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

результат который я получил

[image]

По середине экрана мы видим полосу градиента, но мне нужно две полосы, одна которая будет ближе к правому верхнему углу и вторая которая будет ближе к левому нижнему углу.

Но в `gradient` возможно добавить только `start, center, end`.

Вопрос - как сделать, чтоб было две полосы градиента?

Comment: вариант сделать vector drawable в xml и там можно указать неограниченное количество "полос"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я сделал это так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerColor="#03DAC5"
                android:centerX="0.7"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:centerColor="#03DAC5"
                android:centerX="0.3"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```